# Clear the text when edit receives focus

Tags: c++, winapi

Field has default text
[image: 1]

I have an edit with some default text. How do I clear the text when edit receives focus.

```
        hEdit=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
            "EDIT",
            "",
            WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|
            ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
            5,
            85,
            200,
            30,
            hwnd,
            (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_EDIT,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            NULL);
        HGDIOBJ hfDefault=GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
        SendMessage(hEdit,
            WM_SETFONT,
            (WPARAM)hfDefault,
            MAKELPARAM(FALSE,0));
        SendMessage(hEdit,
            WM_SETTEXT,
            NULL,
            (LPARAM)"Click here, before scan QR!");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear the text when edit receives the focus use the [SetWindowText()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546(v=vs.85).aspx) function while handling the [EN_SETFOCUS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761685(v=vs.85).aspx) notification:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    if (HIWORD(wParam) == EN_SETFOCUS && LOWORD(wParam) == IDC_MAIN_EDIT)
    {
        SetWindowText(hEdit, 0);
    }
}
break;
```

Comment: as expected when i add SetWindowText to
**case IDC_MAIN_EDIT:{if(fieldSelected == false){SetWindowText(hEdit,0);fieldSelected = true; }}break;**
it delete text from field. but how to stop deleteng every time I writing something?

Comment: This is overkill; Windows supports this already with [`EM_SETCUEBANNER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761639(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

The *best* way to do this is to send the text box the [`EM_SETCUEBANNER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761639.aspx) message, which sets a "cue banner". This is placeholder text that is automatically displayed by the operating system when the textbox is empty.

This will not only make your code simpler, but it will create a user experience that is more consistent with other applications, thus making your application easier to use.

Comment: What's more, using the cue banner also solves a problem, the OP hadn't even considered yet: Once the user deletes the entire contents, the cue banner re-appears.

Comment: On a second thought, what the OP probably really wants to do is have a USB-attached QR code scanner place the contents into a user-selected edit control. I don't know, why they rely on user-coöperation for this, though, instead of simply setting the input focus. Either way, they will have to make sure, that focus doesn't leave the control when the click the *"Ok"* button.

Comment: And doesn't the button grab focus when they click OK? They would have to give focus back to the edit control afterward, assuming Windows doesn't call `SetFocus()` again after the `WM_COMMAND` returns. There's probably a better way to do this...

Comment: The *correct* option would be to not rely on a QR scanner that sends its text to a focused UI control in the first place. Most QR/barcode scanners can place scanned data on the clipboard, or send the data to a user-defined window or callback, or send it as a broadcast message.